# My phone got bricked by encryption - any ideas how to fix it?

Tags: rom-flashing, custom-roms, twrp, unbricking, xiaomi

So I wanted to root my Redmi Note 5 pro and install a custom ROM but sadly I bricked it in the process. It started when TWRP (3.3.1-0-whyred) told me to enter a password that didn't exist. Googled it, "default_password" didn't work, my MI ID password didn't work and other than that there was NO password used on the whole phone (did a factory reset before I started messing with it).

I just pressed cancel because I thought it was a bug, wiped the phone with "format data" in TWRP and installed Resurrection Remix OS V7 + magisk. Wiped the cache, rebooted, performed the first time setup and everything was dandy... Except for the fact that **instead of 64gb of storage I only had 16**.

So I tried it again. And again. Didn't work. Then I found multiple people online with the same phone and the same problem who said you should change /data to another file system and then change it back. **It was f2s2 so I changed it to ext4, rebooted to recovery, changed it back to f2s2, rebooted to recovery again et voilà, I was back to 64gb of storage**. I did the standard TWRP factory reset, installed the ROM again and booted back to the OS. I got to the splash screen but after loading for a few minutes it takes me back to recovery mode. Now I'm stuck.

After installing a FW-less ROM of MIUI 9 (didn't wanna risk using a rom with FW since triggering anti rollback on Xiaomi phones causes hard brick) it says this when I boot it: "**Encryption was interrupted and can't be completed. As a result, the data on your phone is no longer accessible**". There's a reset phone button that just takes me back to recovery.

I tried three different recovery tools (TWRP, Red Wolf and Orange Fox), wiped everything multiple times, installed RR OS a few times, tried changing the file format of /data to all the different formats and install it again and finally I downloaded a Xiaomi MIUI ROM with FW but that only takes me to the "encryption failed" screen as well.

Sooooo... Time to buy a new phone or can this one be saved?

Comment: Check dmesg/logcat using `pstore` after a failed boot attempt. If it's FDE, formatting `/data` would have left no space for encryption footer.

Comment: @IrfanLatif sorry I'm very new to this, do I need to use the terminal in recovery mode or fastboot on my pc and what exactly should I type? Thanks for your quick answer

Comment: of course you can fix this, no need for new phone. magisk may have caused this. after clean install (ROM+FW) disable encryption with no-verity-opt-encrypt before flashing magisk and don't flash Zackptg5's disabler

Comment: @alecxs mate I could kiss your face right now, using no-verity-opt-encrypt worked, my phone's back in working order :D

Comment: @JeffAl-Même and encryption works after that? I mean when enabled from settings.